# Handle newlines explicitly only in part of an ANTLR grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I'm currently developing a parser for an old proprietary markup-like language which has to be converted to a newer standard. I'm using ANTLR 4 for that.

The structure is composed by blocks delimited by a specific starter and its relative terminator (eg. `{` ... `}`, `<` ... `>`, `INPUT` ... `END`). Inside each block, elements are specified in rows, separated by newlines; actually, only somewhere these newlines are needed to understand what code means.

For example:

```
< ID
SOME_VAR "optional modifier string"
$anEnvironmentVariable
"a constant string"
"another constant" "with its optional modifier"
>
```

A parser rule like the following

```
field
  : OPEN_ANGLED_BRACKET row_id
    ((ENVIRONMENT_VAR | DQUOTE_STR | VAR) DQUOTE_STR?)+
    CLOSED_ANGLED_BRACKET
  ;

// [...]

WHITESPACE
  : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
  ;
```

can easily parse the above example, but because newlines are ignored, it can't actually distinguish if a double-quoted string is a constant (meaning it's at the start of the line) or a modifier string (which follows a previous variable/constant in the same line).

I could actually explicitly handle the newline like this:

```
field
  : OPEN_ANGLED_BRACKET row_id NEWLINE
    ((ENVIRONMENT_VAR | DQUOTE_STR | VAR) DQUOTE_STR? NEWLINE)+
    CLOSED_ANGLED_BRACKET NEWLINE
  ;

// [...]

WHITESPACE
  : [ \t] -> skip
  ;

NEWLINE
  : '\r'? '\n'
  | '\r'
  ;
```

but then I must explicitly handle newline ***everywhere*** in the rest of the grammar, complicating it by a lot!

Is there any way to keep explicit newline confined inside angled brakets, skipping it everywhere else "automatically"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [lexical modes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes) here. You'd have to define separate lexer- and parser grammars to use lexical modes.

Whenever you encounter a `ENVIRONMENT_VAR`, `VAR` or `DQUOTE_STR` in the lexer (the first value in a row), you change the lexical mode. In this new lexical mode you match 3 things: strings, spaces (which you skip) and new lines (which you also skip and after this token, you change back to the default mode). This all might sound a bit vague, so here's a short demo of it all:

#### File: MarkupLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar MarkupLexer;

ENVIRONMENT_VAR       : '$' VAR    -> mode(MODIFIER_MODE);
VAR                   : [a-zA-Z_]+ -> mode(MODIFIER_MODE);
DQUOTE_STR            : STR        -> mode(MODIFIER_MODE);
OPEN_ANGLED_BRACKET   : '<';
CLOSED_ANGLED_BRACKET : '>';
SPACES                : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;

fragment STR : '"' ~["\r\n]* '"';

mode MODIFIER_MODE;

  MODIFIER_MODE_SPACES : [ \t] -> skip;
  MODIFIER_MODE_NL     : [\r\n]+ -> skip, mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
  MODIFIER_MODE_STRING : STR;
```

The parser will look like this:

#### File: MarkupParser.g4

```
parser grammar MarkupParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=MarkupLexer;
}

field
  : OPEN_ANGLED_BRACKET row_id row+ CLOSED_ANGLED_BRACKET
  ;

row
 : (ENVIRONMENT_VAR | DQUOTE_STR | VAR) MODIFIER_MODE_STRING?
 ;

row_id
 : VAR
 ;
```

When you parse the input:

```
< ID
SOME_VAR "optional modifier string"
$anEnvironmentVariable
"a constant string"
"another constant" "with its optional modifier"
>
```

you will get the following parse tree:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I think that lexical modes were exactly what I was needing.
I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to come up with a solution that doesn't use lexer modes (as I find them ugly) and therefore modified Bart's grammar:

```
grammar SOGrammar;

start:
    OPEN_ANGLED_BRACKET ROW_ID ROW* CLOSED_ANGLED_BRACKET
;

VAR:             [a-zA-Z_]+;
ENVIRONMENT_VAR: '$' VAR;
DQUOTE_STR:      '"' .*? '"';

OPEN_ANGLED_BRACKET: '<';
CLOSED_ANGLED_BRACKET: '>';

ROW_ID: VAR LINEBREAK;
ROW:
    (ENVIRONMENT_VAR | DQUOTE_STR | VAR) (SPACE* DQUOTE_STR)? LINEBREAK
;

SPACE: [ \t] -> skip;
LINEBREAK: [\r\n] -> skip;
```

The idea here is that a row can be handled entirely in the lexer where we have control over whitespaces.

The parse tree is:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the alternative approach, I think it's very cool.
The problem I can find in this solution is that ROW is one single big token, and the tree that results from parsing doesn't actually understand for each row if I'm having a modifier string or not in that row.
It's true that I can rather easily inspect the token when visiting the tree, but I think that Bart's solution is more straightforward.

Comment: Mike, what did you render the parse tree with? it looks awesome.

Comment: @Petruza That's from my ANTLR4 extension for Visual Studio Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4.